# VBA code, If cells in a certain column contain a certain word in need to cut and paste the entire row on to a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA code for the following:

If cells in a certain column contain a certain word, I need to cut and paste the entire row onto a different sheet. I found some code, but it matches the row on the destination sheet.  I just need it to go on to the different sheet and be deleted from the source.

Can anyone kindly advise?

Comment: Help us to help you... **Post your current code.**

Comment: Post your data screenshot and parts of code where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

if your "Column" has a header as its first cell then you can use `AutoFilter()` as per following code (see comments to adjust it to your actual needs)

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("mySheetName") '<--| reference the worksheet with data (change "mySheetName" to your actual worksheet with data name
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its "column" (change "A" occurrences to your actual column with data index)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="d" '<--| change "word" to your actual word to be looked for
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    .Copy Worksheets("myOtherSheetName").Range("A1")
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End With
            End If
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) Unfortunately this only deleted all the contents of the "mySheetName" worksheet. I changed the names of the worksheets, the range, and the "word". And I got an error that says "no cells were found".  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?